# Algorithm to find minimum no.of sides of a polygon

Tags: algorithm

How to design an algorithm to find minimum no.of sides of a polygon which lies between two **concentric** circles?

Similar to this:

[image: circles]

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot to demonstrate your point?

Comment: Moreover, it would be better to elaborate on some idea / effort you have already done

Comment: Something like this - http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/MathOverflow/Annulus.jpg

Comment: How is the circle in screenshot, concentric??

Comment: Ya in screenshot there are two circles with almost same radii. But in my question the radii can be anything.

Comment: I don't see how this would need much of an algorithm; it should be formulaic.  I would expect http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to look.

Comment: @mark thank you.I also have to solve this by greedy approach. That is next requirement.

Comment: @fayyazkl I know one approach but I am not able to convert into a proper algorithm

Comment: Take any line tangent to the inner circle.  Calculate the points where that tangent intersects the outer circle.  Those two points and the center of the circle(s) describe an arc.  Calculate `ceil(2pi / arc_angle)`; this is the number of sides required.

Comment: What is the input to the algorithm?  What is the output of the algorithm?  Provide a __complete__ example input and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the simplest case first: the inner circle is microscopically small.  The minimum number of sides is 3, as long as the inner circle has a non-zero radius.

When does the polygon start needing 4 sides?  Draw an equilateral triangle inscribed in the circle.  The polygon starts needing 4 sides when the inner circle's radius reaches the center point of the sides of the triangle.

If you inscribe a regular polygon of N sides into the outer circle, you can compute the distance from the midpoint of each side to the center of the circle using the cosine rule:

```
distance_to_midpoint = cos ( 360 / (N * 2) ) * radius_of_outer_circle
```

(Explanation: if you make a isosceles triangle using the center point of the circle to the side in question, the radii have an angle of 360 / N.  Divide the triangle in half at the side's midpoint to form a right-angle triangle with hypotenuse equal to the radius of the outer circle, then use cosine rule)

Now `distance_to_midpoint` needs to be greater than or equal to the radius of the inner circle, so solve for `N`:

```
radius_of_inner_circle = cos(360 / (N * 2)) * radius_of_outer_circle
cos(360 / (N*2)) = radius_of_inner_circle / radius_of_outer_circle
360 / (N*2) = acos(radius_i / radius_o)
N = 180 / (acos(radius_i / radius_o))
```

(I haven't double checked this math, and it's really late).

Comment: I didn't check the maths either, I let Mathematica do it, and it agrees with you.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the radius of the polygon, which is the radius of the circumcircle of the polygon, by `R`.  The radius of the inscribed circle is

```
r = R*Cos[180°/n]
```

Solve this for `n`, eliminate the spurious solution which gives a negative result, and you have

```
n = 180°/ArcCos[r/R]
```

You'll have to fiddle around a bit to get an integer value for `n`, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw a tangent to the inner circle, mark A, B - intersections of the tangent with the outer circle.
2. Draw a tangent (different) to the inner circle from point B, mark the intersection with outer circle C.
3. Repeat the procedure (2) until the new tangent crosses first tangent AB.

This algorithm will ensure you cover the maximum radial section at each step, thus minimizing the number of sides in the resulting polygon.

If you only want to find number of sides, it's enough to find an angle between 2 tangents to the inner circle coming from the same point on the outer circle and calculate how many such angles comprise the full 360 degrees (add 1 if there is a remainder) - like @cheeken suggested in comment